# scheduler for Web-application

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, windows-services

I will be writing a Windows Service which will give a call to a class of my Web Application periodically.
What are the possible ways of achieving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something similar to this,using a timer:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{ 
        var timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(DoSomething);
        //do something every 30 seconds
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30).TotalMilliseconds; 
        timer.Start();
}

private void DoSomething(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    //Do your timed event here...
}
```

Comment: i concede to your more explicit answer.

Comment: @brendan:I got error Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler' on 4th line

Comment: right, sorry, fixed that - the Elapsed has to be new ElapsedEvenHandler

Answer (score 0):

a [timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx)?

Comment: actually yes,but from windows service

Comment: see @brendan's answer for a windows service example

Comment: could that be a part of my web-application? please guide

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Quartz.NET.

"Quartz.NET is a full-featured, open source job scheduling system that can be used from smallest apps to large scale enterprise systems."

I've use it when ever I need scheduling of some type.

Comment: not sure this is applicable.  it may reduce/remove the need for the windows service, but i doubt it could be used to trigger anything inside the windows service itself.

Comment: The Quartz.net scheduler is just a library which makes it easy to run jobs, a job being a piece of code within your app or within a dll. The schedule has advanced timing features like run on the first day of then month from 12PM to 6AM, and other nice features. It might be a bit of an overkill for this post but some of quartz features can be helpfull.

Comment: sounds neat.  i suppose i should have done my research before commenting, just assumed it would be more of a "system" than a library from the quote provided.

Comment: All good, yeah you should take a look sometimes its really really great Library.